# Docker - Run an HTML file in docker

Tags: html, ubuntu, docker, dockerfile, docker-container

I want to build a docker container which can run an HTML file on any system by just requiring the user to type `docker run...`. 
This is the HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 20px 5%;
      color: white;
      font-family: Sabon, serif;
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 800px;
    }
    @media (min-width: 600px) {
    }
  </style>
  <head>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <title>D & T</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <center>   
    <div id="headline">
      <header>
        <h1>Date and Time</h1>
        <p></p>
      </header>
      <div id="blurb">
        <p>This page will show you your current local time.</p> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="section1">
      <h2></h2>
      <p>It is now</p>
    </div>
    <div id="section2">
      <script type="text/javascript">
      document.write ('<p>----<span id="date-time">', new Date().toLocaleString(), '<\/span>----<\/p>')
      if (document.getElementById) onload = function () {
    setInterval ("document.getElementById ('date-time').firstChild.data = new Date().toLocaleString()", 50)
      }
      </script>
    </div>
    <div id="section3">
      <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 5px">
        <i>RG</i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
      <p><i>Created 26 May 2017</i></p>
    </footer>
  </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am currently trying to open the HTML file using an Ubuntu 14.04 environment and using wget to get links2, and then using xdg-open to open the html file. But I'm not getting the page. `docker run...` just does nothing. No errors, but no webpage either. 
This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

USER root

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends xdg-utils

RUN apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends links2

RUN xdg-open datetime.html
```

Any alternatives or correct solutions?

Comment: "run an HTML file" - what do you mean? You want to display this html in a browser or what?

Comment: Yes, in a browser. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a service to expose the HTML (apache or nginx). You can simply run `$ docker run --name some-nginx -v /some/content:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d nginx`, where `some/content` links to your HTML file. Here's a link to the official Nginx docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/

Comment: I followed the official Nginx docker instructions, but after doing `docker run --name xyz -d -p 8080:80 abc`, I just get a long string like so: `8ezsh23dfg4fgh23...` What is it and what does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Check you docker machine ip with:

```
docker-machine ip
```

It will give for example: 192.168.99.100 When your container will be runing then in given IP you can check result (for example http://192.168.99.100/)
Place your index.html file in same folder where is your Dockerfile. Your Dockerfile can look like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

COPY index.html /var/www/html/
```

When files will be ready go to their folder and run:

```
docker build -t my_html_file .
docker run -p 80:80 my_html_file
```

And visit http://192.168.99.100/

Comment: How do I 'visit' the ip? As in, where exactly do I type it? I did the above, but after doing `docker run -p 80:80 my_html_file`, I get nothing. Just a new command line.

Comment: @user7091463 Open your browser and paste your adress ip into it to display your html.